# Is the Legendre symbol (9/8) the same as Legendre symbol $3^2/2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol

Is the Legendre symbol (9/8) the same as Legendre symbol $3^2/2$? if so, by what property?

Comment: in the definition of Legendre symbol, the bottom number is prime

Comment: That isn't a Legendre symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question does not make sense as stated,

because, in the definition of [Legendre symbol](https://brilliant.org/wiki/legendre-symbol/), the bottom number is an odd prime.